# How to cross compile a DLL source for Mac OSX, Linux, Android, etc

Tags: c#, c++, macos, unity-game-engine, dll

I've recently become aware of the following open source project, which is a plugin allowing for alembic cache files (exported from popular 3D applications) to be streamed into Unity. Currently, the library has a plugin which can be compiled to produce the necessary DLL's for Windows.

https://github.com/unity3d-jp/AlembicImporter/tree/master/Plugin

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the same source to compile on other platforms and how to do it. Is it possible? Would the source need to change?

Comment: If the source code is written in a portable manner, why not?

Comment: If the source code is written for multiple platform, it would separate code that works on all platform and code that works only for specific platform. During compilation of the source code, the compiler would receive direction to pick which version of the platform-specific code (like code for windows, linux or mac) to use.

Comment: may be just try it. vmware can help, or just borrow someone else's mac, windows pc, or linux pc.

Comment: unity uses .NET 2.0 in most cases. so if the dll is written in .NET 2.0 it will get compiled on anything through Unity.